# SCRIPT ERROR: @lscustoms/lscustoms.lua:355: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

i was trying to implement something into my script and i don't know why i get that error when i try to enter into lscustoms (this script is made for fivem, it lets you tune your car) and then i got blackscreen -

> SCRIPT ERROR:
>   @lscustoms/lscustoms.lua:355: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)
>   DriveInGarage (@lscustoms/lscustoms.lua:355
>   fn (@lscustoms/lscustoms.lua:719)

-- Code :
From line 339 to line 360

```
        local m = LSCMenu.categories:addSubMenu("LIGHTS", "Lights", "Improved night time visibility.",true)
        AddMod(22,LSCMenu.categories.Lights,"HEADLIGHTS", "Headlights", nil, false)
    if not IsThisModelABike(GetEntityModel(veh)) then
            m = m:addSubMenu("NEON KITS", "Neon kits", nil, true)
                m:addSubMenu("NEON LAYOUT", "Neon layout", nil, true)
                    local btn = m["Neon layout"]:addPurchase("None")
                    for n, mod in pairs(LSC_Config.prices.neonlayout) do
                        local btn = m["Neon layout"]:addPurchase(mod.name,mod.price)
                    end

            m = m:addSubMenu("NEON COLOR", "Neon color", nil, true)
                for n, mod in pairs(LSC_Config.prices.neoncolor) do
                    local btn = m:addPurchase(mod.name,mod.price)btn.neon = mod.neon
            end

            m = m:addSubMenu("XENON COLOR", "Xenon color", nil, true)
                for n, mod in pairs(LSC_Config.prices.xenoncolor) do
                local btn = m:addPurchase(mod.name,mod.price)btn.xenon = mod.xenon
                local btn = m:addPurchase("Stock")
                myveh.xenonColor = -1
            end
        end
```

from 682 to 757

```
--Magical loop that allows you to  drive in garage if you successfully go through checks
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        --If you are not already in garage
        if inside == false then
            local ped = LocalPed()
            --Well... yes... we actually need a car to do something
            if IsPedSittingInAnyVehicle(ped) then
                local veh = GetVehiclePedIsUsing(ped)
                --If the vehicle exist, player is in driver seat and if this vehicle is a car or bike then we are good to go
                if DoesEntityExist(veh) and GetPedInVehicleSeat(veh, -1) == ped and (IsThisModelACar(GetEntityModel(veh)) or IsThisModelABike(GetEntityModel(veh)))  then
                    --So lets go through every garage
                    for i,pos in ipairs(garages) do
                        --Lets take the outside coords of garage
                        outside = pos.drivein   
                        --Old enter:If vehicle is close enough, then text will be displayed - Press ENTER to enter garage
                        if LSC_Config.oldenter then         
                            --So, if vehicle is close enough then we can continue
                            if GetDistanceBetweenCoords(outside.x,outside.y,outside.z,GetEntityCoords(ped)) <= f(5) then
                                --Lets check if our vehicle is not in the model black list, and if it is not then we can go further
                                if not tableContains(LSC_Config.ModelBlacklist,GetDisplayNameFromVehicleModel(GetEntityModel(veh)):lower()) then
                                    --If the garage is locked
                                    if pos.locked then
                                        --If the config lock system is not enabled then we can go traight in garage, but if it is enabled then not
                                        if not LSC_Config.lock then
                                            inside = true
                                            currentpos = pos
                                            currentgarage = i
                                            DriveInGarage()
                                        else
                                            drawTxt("~r~Asteapta, este deja cineva",4,1,0.5,0.8,1.0,255,255,255,255)
                                        end
                                    else
                                        inside = true
                                        currentpos = pos
                                        currentgarage = i
                                        DriveInGarage()
                                    end
                                else
                                    drawTxt("~r~Masina nu a fost modificata",4,1,0.5,0.8,1.0,255,255,255,255)
                                end
                            end
                        else
                            --So, if vehicle is close enough and it's facing the garage then we can continue
                            if math.abs(GetEntityHeading(veh)-outside.heading) <= 90 and IsVehicleStopped(veh) and GetDistanceBetweenCoords(outside.x,outside.y,outside.z,GetEntityCoords(ped)) <= f(5) then
                                --Lets check if our vehicle is not in the model black list, and if it is not then we can go further
                                if not tableContains(LSC_Config.ModelBlacklist,GetDisplayNameFromVehicleModel(GetEntityModel(veh)):lower()) then
                                    --If the garage is locked
                                    if pos.locked then
                                        --If the config lock system is not enabled then we can go traight in garage, but if it is enabled then not
                                        if not LSC_Config.lock then
                                            inside = true
                                            currentpos = pos
                                            currentgarage = i
                                            DriveInGarage()
                                        else
                                            drawTxt("~r~Asteapta, este deja cineva",4,1,0.5,0.8,1.0,255,255,255,255)
                                        end
                                    else
                                        inside = true
                                        currentpos = pos
                                        currentgarage = i
                                        DriveInGarage()
                                    end
                                else
                                    drawTxt("~r~Masina nu a fost modificata",4,1,0.5,0.8,1.0,255,255,255,255)
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

If someone know what i was do wrong , please tell me :}

Comment: Error message says that `LSC_Config.prices.xenoncolor` is `nil`

Comment: OK. I've been trying to make it work for a day but I can't. Do you have any idea what I could do to them?

Comment: Try to replace `LSC_Config.prices.xenoncolor` with `LSC_Config.prices.xenoncolor or {}`

Comment: make sure you understand why...